# How to cut mp4 file and link to make webm

Tags: video-player, video-editor, video-conversion, mp4, webm

Whats the fastest way to cut small sections of a mp4 file and link them back together as a WEBm help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: IMO ffmpeg is the easiest way to edit a video. Graphical options include openshot and handbrake, but they do not cut and splice as easily.

Comment: Iv'e been searching up how to use it and it's rather complicated, can you give me a command line example of how to split a 20 min video into 3 sections and unionise them into a single WEBm?

Comment: Why are you splitting it that way only to rejoin ? `ffmpeg -y -i your.MPG -s 480x320 -threads 8 -f webm -vcodec libvpx -deinterlace -g 120 -level 216 -profile 0 -qmax 42 -qmin 10 -rc_buf_aggressivity 0.95 -vb 2M -acodec libvorbis -aq 90 -ac 2 your.webm`'

Comment: I'm trying to cut out the good parts of a video so I combine it in to one short webm

Comment: ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 -ss = start -t = duration

Answer (score 0):

> *I am placing here portions of **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676165/9598)** at [MTS video files - how to merge and convert multiple files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639250/mts-video-files-how-to-merge-and-convert-multiple-files)
>   in the understand that what you wish is to edit videos and create a
>   new video with the slices. If I am wrong please let me know in order
>   to change this answer.*

What you need seems to be a Non Linear Editing System (NLES), which will allow you to place your portions of video (scenes) in a timeline in order to arrange them in the position they should be so that you can "view" a one single video scene playing.

In addition, you can manipulate your video by adding improvements like color correction, gamma, brightness and contrast adjustment and other useful things.

If you wish you can also slice your scenes and remove portions of each video clip and finally do a render of your video production into a single file.

Ubuntu is plenty of useful tools for even real time video processing but if you are used to Windows/Mac Software you will feel comfortable with **KDENlive** (https://kdenlive.org/) and **Openshot** (http://openshot.org/).

My favorite is kdenlive so I am going to place this screenshots over here in order to illustrate the timeline video placement:

[image]

In this timeline I am using 2 Video sources and 1 picture. 1 of the videos is having the "Curves" plugin and I am adjusting brightness level with that plugin. As you can see, kdenlive provides several tools for audio/video levels monitoring so that you can achieve professional results from your production.

By using the "Render" button, you can create a new video in whichever format you wish and adjust the parameters of your new creations. You can even save profiles for using later and do batch rendering.

Good luck!