# MTS video files - how to merge and convert multiple files

Tags: video, video-conversion

I have just recorded a video using my Sony video camera.
It is splited in 4 files (2.1 GB for each file). 
I'd like to merge them and convert the resulting file to another format (smaller size).

What software could I use? I prefer a software with GUI.

I have tried `MKVtoolNix` but it does not work: it creates a file as big as the sum of the 4 files I have (so 8.4 GB), but it is actually the first file so the other 3 files have not been merged to the first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need seems to be a Non Linear Editing System (NLES), which will allow you to place your portions of video (scenes) in a timeline in order to arrange them in the position they should be so that you can "view" a one single video scene playing.

In addition, you can manipulate your video by adding improvements like color correction, gamma, brightness and contrast adjustment and other useful things.

If you wish you can also slice your scenes and remove portions of each video clip and finally do a render of your video production into a single file.

Ubuntu is plenty of useful tools for even real time video processing but if you are used to Windows/Mac Software you will feel comfortable with **KDENlive** (https://kdenlive.org/) and **Openshot** (http://openshot.org/).

My favorite is kdenlive so I am going to place this screenshots over here in order to illustrate the timeline video placement:

[image]

In this timeline I am using 2 Video sources and 1 picture. 1 of the videos is having the "Curves" plugin and I am adjusting brightness level with that plugin. As you can see, kdenlive provides several tools for audio/video levels monitoring so that you can achieve professional results from your production.

I used to work for TV/Radio Stations the last 20 years so let's say I worked with many digital audio/video file formats as from 1999. The Sony MTS is, if I don't mistake, a MP4 container unless you changed that from the options of your camcorder (if the camcorder features such function, of course) so you can mux/transcode the video files into a different file format without losing quality.

When it is about muxing/remuxing/transcoding the very best GUI Tool for ffmpeg/avconv/mencoder seems to be the **Mobile Media Converter by Miksoft** (https://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php) of which I am going to illustrate as follows:

[image]

MMC will also allow you to rip from DVD and Download from YouTube.

So. If you're involved in professional video editing you may agree that manipulating huge video files it a hard work. Unfortunately there's no "automatic" procedures if you wish to get stunning results.

But you're on your way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this: http://www.videohelp.com/software/tsMuxeR It's a free program to merge/stitch your files. Just click 'add' and subsequent files you add with the 'join' button (so NOT the add button, you only use that for the first file). I used the default settings which will output a .ts file, which Openshot can load just fine.

As for the gentleman's answer above me:

> What you need seems to be a Non Linear Editing System (NLES), which will allow you to place your portions of video (scenes) in a timeline in order to arrange them in the position they should be so that you can "view" a one single video scene playing.

I don't know how you do it but I sure like to know because when I drop MTS files in a non-linear video editor like Openshot the files don't get properly merged/stitched. There is always a second or two where the transition between one and the next MTS file isn't properly done; the video stutters and the audio drops. So right now those files have to be merged each time before editing the recording (i.e. the totality of all files).