# Software for converting and cutting videos with webm support

Tags: software-recommendation, files, video-conversion, webm

I am looking for a file converting program to  trim and convert videos into `.webm` format. I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `ffmpeg` program:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:08 output.webm
```

This should get 8 seconds (`-t 00:00:08`) of `input.mp4` (starting 3 seconds into the video `-ss 00:00:03`) and put them to `output.webm` as result, i.e. the cut-out is form second 3 to second 11 (don't nail me down if the 3 or the 11 is included then ... )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffmpeg` program. See [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04) and FFmpeg [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for the instructions on how to install this program.

After the installation you can convert an `.avi` video, for eg,  by:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi foo.webm
```

With only this `raw conversion` the quality might not be the best you will get. You'll have to use 'exotic' audio/video/transcoding options while converting. One suggested way is, for eg:

```
avconv -i foo.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -aq 5 -ac 2 -qmax 25 -threads 2 foo.webm
```

where:

- `-acodec libvorbis` is audio codec for WebM
- `-aq` is audio quality
- `ac` is the number of audio channels
- `-qmax` quantization/compression level for video
- `threads` how many CPUs should be used while transcoding

[This](http://daniemon.com/blog/how-to-convert-videos-to-webm-with-ffmpeg/) and [this](http://paulrouget.com/e/converttohtml5video/) blog posts will give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

> *Parts from this answer comes from **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676165/9598)** at [MTS video files - how to merge and convert multiple files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639250/mts-video-files-how-to-merge-and-convert-multiple-files/676165#676165)*

When it is about muxing/remuxing/transcoding the very best GUI Tool for ffmpeg/avconv/mencoder seems to be the **Mobile Media Converter by Miksoft** (https://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php) of which I am going to illustrate as follows:

[image]

MMC will also allow you to rip from DVD and Download from YouTube.

Please see [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/25532/9598) at [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files) for a detailed explanation about compression.

Good luck!